# Is There any gem in rails which confirm approval from admin before edit in record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am trying to make an web application using which a user will edit some posts, and after confirmation of administrator user these changes will reflect in POST table (Model). is there any GEM which can do this task.
Just for the sake of example we can named this system Dynamic Approval System.
Sorry for my bad elaboration,  :)

Comment: I think your question has already been asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542041/how-to-setup-admin-approval-a-models-edits

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [`Draftsman`](https://github.com/liveeditor/draftsman)

> Draftsman is a Ruby gem that lets you create draft versions of your
>   database records. If you're developing a system in need of simple
>   drafts or a publishing approval queue, then Draftsman just might be
>   what you need.

Comment: thanku, Draftsman is also a option but i got **Audited** more specific for m problem.https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited