# Rails Deep Model Versioning with Approval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My model is related to other models via `has_many` relation, is there a known gem there or recommended approach which would make it easy to version each update? at least two levels deep?

I already searched for model versioning in rails, I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229515/rails-model-versioning-with-approval), the answer mentioned [vestal_versions](https://github.com/bousquet/vestal_versions) gem a solution, but how to version related models too? which `belongs_to` my model directly?

My final goal, is not to update stories before admin approve the update.

**EDIT**

I thought about an idea that I like to share:

Models:

```
Story 
has_one :content

StoryContent
belngs_to :story
```

Now, when a new update take place, I create a new Content model, then when approved I simple change content_id of `Story` to the approved `StoryContent` model.

Thus, when an attempt to edit a story, I will not update the same Story at controller, instead I will create a new pending `StoryContent` and view a message that we will review the update .. etc

So, how about that?